# find and replace a text in different header for each section in docx using java

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi, docx

I am trying to find and replace a text different sections of header in each page using Apache poi but getting only null data, but Docx has different header sections and footer too

```
    package com.concretepage;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
    import org.apache.poi.xwpf.model.XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy;
    import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
    import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFFooter;
    import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFHeader;
    public class ReadDOCXHeaderFooter {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("D:/docx/read-test.docx");
                XWPFDocument xdoc=new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(fis));
                XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy policy = new XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy(xdoc);
                //read header
 
                for(int i=0;i<90;i++)
                {
                 XWPFHeader header = policy.getHeader(i);
       List<XWPFRun> runs = header.getRuns();
  if (runs != null) {
         for (XWPFRun r : runs) {
          String text = r.getText(0);
          if (text != null && text.contains("$$key$$")) {
           text = text.replace("$$key$$", "ABCD");//your content
           r.setText(text, 0);
          }
         }
                    System.out.println(header.getText());

                    //read footer
                    XWPFFooter footer = policy.getFooter(i);
                    System.out.println(footer.getText());
                }
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

**1.Screen shot of Docx header sections.**

[image: Docx header sections]

**2.Screen shot of Docx header another section.**

[image: Docx header another section]

**3.Screen shot of Docx header another section.**

[image: Docx header another section]

**4.Screen Shot**

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Please don't change your question into a totally different one. And at least don't change your code into code which not even compiles. Neither [XWPFHeader](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFHeader.html)  nor [XWPFHeaderFooter](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFHeaderFooter.html) has a method `getRuns()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `*.docx` document, which contains multiple sections, each section starts in a paragraph which has section properties set. To get the headers and footers out of section properties there is [public XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy(XWPFDocument doc, org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTSectPr sectPr)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/model/XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.html#XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy-org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument-org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTSectPr-) constructor.

Only the section properties for the last section are set in document's body.

So the following code should get all headers and footers out of all sections in the document.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.model.XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy;

public class ReadWordAllHeaderFooters {

 static void getAllHeaderFooterFromPolicy(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy headerFooterPolicy) {
  XWPFHeader header;
  XWPFFooter footer;
  header = headerFooterPolicy.getDefaultHeader();
  if (header != null) System.out.println("DefaultHeader: " + header.getText());
  header = headerFooterPolicy.getFirstPageHeader();
  if (header != null) System.out.println("FirstPageHeader: " + header.getText());
  header = headerFooterPolicy.getEvenPageHeader();
  if (header != null) System.out.println("EvenPageHeader: " + header.getText());
  header = headerFooterPolicy.getOddPageHeader();
  if (header != null) System.out.println("OddPageHeader: " + header.getText());

  footer = headerFooterPolicy.getDefaultFooter();
  if (footer != null) System.out.println("DefaultFooter: " + footer.getText());
  footer = headerFooterPolicy.getFirstPageFooter();
  if (footer != null) System.out.println("FirstPageFooter: " + footer.getText());
  footer = headerFooterPolicy.getEvenPageFooter();
  if (footer != null) System.out.println("EvenPageFooter: " + footer.getText());
  footer = headerFooterPolicy.getOddPageFooter();
  if (footer != null) System.out.println("OddPageFooter: " + footer.getText());
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("MultipleHeaderFooters.docx"));
  XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy headerFooterPolicy;

  //are there paragraphs to start sections?
  int section = 1;
  for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : document.getParagraphs()) {
   if (paragraph.getCTP().isSetPPr()) { //paragraph has paragraph properties set
    if (paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().isSetSectPr()) { //paragraph property has section properties set
     //headers and footers in paragraphs section properties:
     headerFooterPolicy = new XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy(document, paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getSectPr());
     System.out.println("headers and footers in section properties of section " + section++ + ":");
     getAllHeaderFooterFromPolicy(headerFooterPolicy);
    }
   }
  }

  //headers and footers in documents body = headers and footers of last section:
  headerFooterPolicy = new XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy(document);
  System.out.println("headers and footers in documents body = headers and footers of last section " + section + ":");
  getAllHeaderFooterFromPolicy(headerFooterPolicy);

 }
}
```

Comment: i looking to find a text in header and footer text and replace with some other text

Comment: No, because that was not the question here. But the code gets the headers and footers as [XWPFHeaderFooter](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFHeaderFooter.html). So ask another question which shows where you are stuck in getting the paragraphs and text runs from `XWPFHeaderFooter` and replacing some text in the text runs.

Answer (score 2):

This function should do the job

```
static void replaceHeaderText(XWPFDocument document, String searchValue, String replacement)
{
    List<XWPFHeader> headers = document.getHeaderList();
    for(XWPFHeader h : headers)
    {
        for (XWPFParagraph p : h.getParagraphs()) {
            List<XWPFRun> runs = p.getRuns();
            if (runs != null) {
                for (XWPFRun r : runs) {
                    String text = r.getText(0);
                    if (text != null && text.contains(searchValue)) {
                        text = text.replace(searchValue, replacement);
                        r.setText(text, 0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (XWPFTable tbl : h.getTables()) {
            for (XWPFTableRow row : tbl.getRows()) {
                for (XWPFTableCell cell : row.getTableCells()) {
                    for (XWPFParagraph p : cell.getParagraphs()) {
                        for (XWPFRun r : p.getRuns()) {
                            String text = r.getText(0);
                            if (text != null && text.contains(searchValue)) {
                                text = text.replace(searchValue, replacement);
                                r.setText(text,0);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet that replaces all the occurrences of a key like `${firstName}` with its String value in an `XWPFDocument`. All the parameters to be replaced will be stored in a `Map<String, String>`.

```
private void replaceParameters(XWPFDocument document, Map<String, String> replacements) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> parameter : replacements.entrySet()) {
        // replaces all occurrences in the headers
        replaceHeadersParams(document.getHeaderList(), parameter);

        // replaces all occurrences in the document's body
        replaceParagraphsParams(document.getParagraphs(), parameter);
        replaceTablesParams(document.getTables(), parameter);

        // replaces all occurrences in the footers
        replaceFootersParams(document.getFooterList(), parameter);
    }
}

private void replaceHeadersParams(List<XWPFHeader> headers, Map.Entry<String, String> paramToReplace) {
    for (XWPFHeader header : headers) {
        replaceParagraphsParams(header.getParagraphs(), paramToReplace);
        replaceTablesParams(header.getTables(), paramToReplace);
    }
}

private void replaceFootersParams(List<XWPFFooter> footers, Map.Entry<String, String> parameter) {
    for (XWPFFooter footer : footers) {
        replaceParagraphsParams(footer.getParagraphs(), parameter);
        replaceTablesParams(footer.getTables(), parameter);
    }
}

private void replaceTablesParams(List<XWPFTable> tables, Map.Entry<String, String> paramToReplace) {
    for (XWPFTable tbl : tables) {
        for (XWPFTableRow row : tbl.getRows()) {
            for (XWPFTableCell cell : row.getTableCells()) {
                replaceParagraphsParams(cell.getParagraphs(), paramToReplace);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Replace the `startIndex` and `endIndex` with your values `$$`. Keep in mind that this implementation replaces all the occurrences ignoring the case.

```
private void replaceParagraphsParams(List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphs, Map.Entry<String, String> paramToReplace) throws POIXMLException {
    for (XWPFParagraph p : paragraphs) {
        for (XWPFRun r : p.getRuns()) {
            String text = r.getText(0);
            if (text != null && text.toLowerCase().contains(paramToReplace.getKey().toLowerCase())) {
                int startIndex = text.indexOf("${");
                int endIndex = text.indexOf("}");
                String toBeReplaced = text.substring(startIndex, endIndex + 1);
                text = text.replace(toBeReplaced, paramToReplace.getValue());
                r.setText(text, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```